# Shell script to control user initiated processes

Tags: linux, scripting, bash

I'm not a shell script expert. I'm looking for a shell script which checks
for maximum number of Java processes (MyJavaStandalone) running in the system 
before starting/executing the current Java process.

**Example:**

Script: */home/myfolder/script.sh*

script.sh contains

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin/java MyJavaStandalone >> $DATE.log &
```

Here, before executing "MyJavaStandalone", if there are already 10 processes
running, then this current process should not be started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, assuming you have the 'procps' tools installed:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $(pgrep -cf "java MyJavaStandalone") < 10 ))
then
    /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin/java MyJavaStandalone >> $DATE.log &
fi
```

Explanation:

The `pgrep` command counts the number of copies of your script currently in the process table.  The `(( ... ))` construct is a simple way to do basic math comparisons and operations in the shell, in this case checking to see if the output of the `pgrep` command is less than 10.

Comment: @Insyte First, thank you for the script.  FYI. -c is an invalid option.  `pgrep: invalid option -- c`

Comment: It must depend on the version; it works on my systems.  You can use `pgrep -f java MyJavaStandalone|wc -l` as a replacement.  I'm running version 3.2.7, by the way.